# Vue Axios - not sure why I can't call a function on this response

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm updating the code of a previous dev and I'm stuck on why I can't do this, as the code is returning this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: failedCallback is not a function
```

This is the function I'm working with:

```
export default {
  get(callback, failedCallback) {
    axios.get(`/admin/shops`)
         .then(response => callback(response.data))
         .catch(errors => failedCallback(errors))
  }
}
```

which is then imported like this:

```
import getShop from '../api/shops'
```

and used like this in my global router guard

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.name == null){
    getShop.get(
      data => {
        if(data.setup) {
          debugger;
          this.$store.dispatch('getBackground', false); #this is the line that causes the error!
          next({ name: 'customers_table'});
        }
        else {
          next({ name: 'plans'})
        }
      });
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
})
```

When I add the below line I get the TypeError

```
this.$store.dispatch('getBackground', false);
```

not sure why I get that error or how to fix it?

EDIT:
This is my `getBackground` action

```
getBackground: ({ commit }, payload) => {
  commit('changeBackground', payload);
}
```

Comment: could you post the error message as well?

Comment: @helper yep its up at the top.. that's the error

Comment: could you post the code for the getBackground action? (That is what's throwing the exception)

Comment: @helper sure thing.. I added it to the OP

Answer (score 1):

Your callback is throwing error which is caught by the catch block. The catch block is trying to call `failedCallback` which you are not providing to `getShop`. Thats why it is raising type error for `failedCallback`.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: failedCallback is not a function
```

Original cause of the error is `this.$store`. Store is not available in router by `this`.

You need to import store in router file like this.

```
import store from '<whereever store is defined>'

store.dispatch('getBackground', false);
```

or import Vue and access store from protptype like this.

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.prototype.$store.dispatch('getBackground', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

you defined a get function which is takes two function in parameters, but you passed one function to it, which the error shows you the failcallback isnot a function:
[image]

and consider that You are not inside a component, so this.$store does not work.
 if you export store like below:
store.js

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
//everything is inside
})
```

you should use:

```
import {store} from './store'
```

or if you used export default, then you should use:

```
import store from './store'
```

then use like below:

store.getters.isAuthenticated

as explained in this topic by linusburg:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-use-vuex-in-router/13520